# Crear un nuevo registro SQL cuando se selecciona un valor en checkcombobox

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress

Buen día,

Necesito que al seleccionar un valor de un combobox de selección múltiple, el mismo me guarde un registro por cada seleccion.

Ejemplo:

Tengo un modulo de envios, en el cual al seleccionar un remitente o varios remitentes, estos se vinculan a ese envio, por lo cual, luego recupero el valor de cada uno de ellos para vincularlos a dicho envio.

Comment: el elemento es un comboBox de windowsForms? Desconozco la propiedad de selección multiple en este control, no as planteado utilizar mejor un listBox?

Comment: Es un combobox de selección multipe con check, es un control del framework DevExpress.

Comment: Y no tiene ningún evento itemChecked o algo así?